# The method searchingStacks(Stack<E>, E) in the type SearchStack<E> is not applicable for the arguments (Stack<String>, String)

Tags: java, generics, stack, queue

I am trying to create a generic method to search a stack for element "e" using a queue and return the stack to its original statues .

but i keep getting the error "The method searchingStacks(Stack, E) in the type SearchStack is not applicable for the arguments (Stack, String) "   when i call the method " searchingStacks "

please help , thank you in advance.

```
import java.util.Stack; 
import java.util.Stack.* ;   

public class SearchStack<E> extends Object {



    public static void main (String [] args ) {

        Stack < String > test = new Stack () ;

        for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i ++ ) {

            test.push("a" + i ) ; }


        System.out.println (test.toString()) ;

        System.out.println ( searchingStacks (test , "a3") ) ;
        }


    public boolean searchingStacks (Stack<E> s1 , E e) {

        boolean result = false ; 
        Queue <E> temp = new LinkedQueue () ;


        while (s1.isEmpty() == false )
        {
            if (s1.peek() == e ) { result = true ; }
            temp.enqueue(s1.pop());
            }

        while (temp.isEmpty() == false ){

            s1.push( temp.dequeue() ) ;
            }

        while (! s1.isEmpty()  ) { temp.enqueue(s1.pop());}
        while (! temp.isEmpty() ) { s1.push(temp.dequeue()) ; }



        return result ;}

}
```

Comment: It seems like you are missing the generic type in the method declaration. Try changing `public boolean searchingStacks (Stack<E> s1 , E e)` to `public <E> boolean searchingStacks (Stack<E> s1 , E e)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`main` method is a static one, so you cannot call `searchingStacks` directly there.
An instance of the class is required to call instance method.

```
public class SearchStack<E> extends Object
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SearchStack<String> ss = new SearchStack<String>();

    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {

        stack.push("a" + i);
    }

    System.out.println(stack.toString());

    System.out.println(ss.searchingStacks(stack, "a3"));
}
...
}
```